# Including unused code during compilation

Tags: c++, makefile

Building my application from Makefile I have found that excluding from code some class and its using doesn't affected on size of the built application.

```
// some file
// #include "SomeClass.h"
.......
void myfunc()
{
     SomeClass _cl;
     // do something with _cl etc...
     // _cl.SomeFunc();
     .........
}


Makefile
......
SOURCES = ... SomeClass.cpp .... etc
```

But If I remove SomeClass.cpp from Makefile then size of the built application really becomes less. Why gcc doesn't optimize compiled code and don't exclude unused SomeClass from final result?

Comment: What compiler flags are you using?

Comment: Don't know if i makes a difference in your case, but try the compilerflag `-Os` to optimize for size.

Comment: without lto gcc can't tell if your class is used from another compilation unit or not.

Comment: Is your application statically linked? If you have dynamic libraries there is no way the compiler can tell if something is not used.

Comment: Hi bolow. Thank you for your advice -lto. I forgot to include it to my makefile,

Answer (score 3):

You can configure this through compile flags. On linux/gcc, unused symbols are not eliminated from the binary - they may be of use when you dl_open() a binary. If you want to eliminate unused code, add -ffunction-sections and -fdata-sections to your compile options and --gc-sections to your linker options. The compile options will ensure that every function is placed in a separate section (as opposed to a section per file), the linker option will throw unused sections away.